# Trying to use a selector to pull from the global state whenever an action is fired

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the global state for an element on a Card component. I am doing so with a react hook. I have gotten this far, whereby the FlipIcon fires off the action to update whether a card is face up or down in the global store:

I am trying to just log it out here:

```
export const MorphemeCard: React.FC<{
  morpheme: Affix;
  position?: Position;
  onReset: () => void;
  onMoved: (position: Position) => void;
}> = ({ morpheme, ...card }) => {
  const [state, { actions, selectors }] = useAppState();
  console.log(selectors.getCardFacing(morpheme.id));

  return (
    <Card
      {...card}
      additionalContent={<span>{morpheme.affix_position}</span>}
      details={morpheme}
    >
      {morpheme.affix_name}
    </Card>
  );
};
[...]
```

Here is where the flip is triggered

```
const Card: React.FC<{
  [...]
}) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<Position>(
    initialPosition ?? { x: 0, y: 0 }
  );
  const [isCardFront, setIsCardFront] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [state, { actions, selectors }] = useAppState();

  function handleFlip() {
    setIsCardFront((isCardFront) => !isCardFront);
    actions.setMorpheme(details, position, isCardFront);
  }

  return (
    <Draggable
      position={position}
      onStop={(_e, { x, y }) => {
        setPosition({ x, y });
        onMoved({ x, y });
      }}
    >
      <CardWrapper>
        <CardTools>
          <FlipIcon onClick={handleFlip} />
          [...]
    </Draggable>
  );
};
```

It hits this in the reducer:

```
 case "set_morpheme": {
      const morphemeIndex = state.morphemes.findIndex((m) => m.id === action.morpheme.id);
      const has = morphemeIndex !== -1;
    
      return {
        ...state,
        morphemes: has
          ? state.morphemes.map((m, index) => {
              if (index === morphemeIndex) {
                return {
                  ...m,
                  position: action.position,
                  isFaceUp: action.isCardFront,
                };
              }
              return m;
            })
          : [
              ...state.morphemes,
              {
                ...action.morpheme,
                position: action.position,
                isFaceUp: action.isCardFront,
              },
            ],
      };
    }
```

and this is the selector

```
 const getCardFacing = useCallback(
    (id: number): boolean | undefined => { 
      const found = state.morphemes.find((m) => m.id === id);
      return found?.isFaceUp;
    }, [state.morphemes]
  );
```

I thought that the selectors instantly pull down the data from the store when ever an action is dispatched?